# Open a file attached to eclipse project in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an excel file attached/imported to my project. How can I open it to a File f using the path?

The following didn't work:

```
File f = new File("Category Coverage Active SKUS.xlsx");
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: the file doesn't seem to be in the correct path. You are getting `File not Found`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you put the file into your src/main/java folder. Try this:

```
File f = new File("src/main/java/Category Coverage Active SKUS.xlsx");
```

In eclipse, the root path is where the .project and the .classpath files are located.

Answer (score 0):

You must put your file in the resource folder.